# Why OnCreateView in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the difference between OnCreate and OnCreateView in the lifecycle of fragments. Also why there is no OnCreateView in Activity life cycle but in frgaments. I am confusion in these two methods.

Please help me with the suggestion as I am very new to android programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCreateView()` allows you to inflate a layout for a fragment and get your views with `findViewById()`.

The fragment's `onCreate()` gets always called directly before the `onCreateView()` method. It does not allow you to setup a fragment layout, so you always have to override `onCreateView()`.
Most times you do not need the fragment's `onCreate()`.

An activity does not need `onCreateView()`, since it has the `setContentView()` method, which allows you to setup a layout in the activity's `onCreate()`.